# Find the probability mass function of $N$ (the number of defects in $R$).

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

The total number of $X$ defects on a chip follows a Poisson distribution parameter
$α (= E [X])$. Suppose each defect has a probability $0 <p <1$ of falling into a region
specific $R$, and that the location is independent of the number of defects. Find the probability mass function of $N$
(the number of defects in $R$).

I don't know how to start with this problem. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't blame you... this is a bit of a confusing question. I am interpreting as follows : you want to find a distribution  $N(x)$, where $x \in \mathbb{N}$, which tells you the probability that a given chip with has $x$ defects in $R$. I think it's easiest to think of this from the "law of total probability" perspective. Followign this, it looks like you will want to solve :

$$ N(x) = \Pr  [x \text{ defects lie in R} | d \text{ defects total}] \cdot \Pr[d \text{ defects total}]$$

The first term is distributed as $Bin(d,p)$, so this would just be the probability that some $X \sim  Bin(d,p) = x $

The second term is just the probability that the given Poisson RV is equal to $d$. So, the whole thing is given as

$$ N(x) = \sum_{d=0..\infty} \dbinom{d}{x} p^x(1-p)^{d-x}\cdot \frac{\lambda^d \cdot \exp [-\lambda]}{d!} $$

This looks pretty ugly, but it's really not that bad to solve. Expanding the rewriting, we have

$$ N(x) =  \sum_{d=x..\infty} \frac{d!}{x!(d-x)!} p^x(1-p)^{d-x}\cdot \frac{\lambda^d \cdot \exp [-\lambda]}{d!} 
\\
= (\frac{p^x}{x!} \cdot \exp[-\lambda] ) \cdot \sum_{d=x..\infty} d!\cdot \frac{(1-p)^{(d-x)}}{(d-x)!} \cdot \frac{\lambda^d}{d!} 
\\
 = (\frac{p^x}{x!} \cdot \exp [-\lambda] )\sum_{d=0..\infty} \lambda ^{x+d} \cdot \frac{(1-p)^{(d)}}{d!} 
\\
 = (\frac{p^x}{x!} \cdot \exp [-\lambda] \cdot \lambda^x ) \sum_{d=0..\infty}  \frac{(\lambda \cdot (1-p))^{(d)}}{d!}
 $$

Note that the sum is now just the power series for $\exp[\lambda \cdot (1-p)]$. So all together we have:

$$N(x) =  \exp[\lambda \cdot (1-p)] \frac{  p^x}{x!} \cdot \exp [-\lambda] \cdot \lambda^x  $$

As Gregory pointed out, this is actally just the expression for Poisson$(\lambda p )$, which can be seen by writing the above as

$$N(x) =  \exp[\lambda] \cdot \exp[-p \lambda] \cdot \frac{  p^x}{x!} \cdot \exp [-\lambda] \cdot \lambda^x  = \frac{\exp[-\lambda p] \cdot (\lambda p)^x}{x!} $$

Comment: I was trying to avoid giving a full solution as I was not sure if this was homework or not. But as you went through the whole thing, you can probably also mention that the expression you found for $N(x)$ is $\text{Poisson}(\lambda p)$ after a minor simplification.

Comment: @Gregory Good point. I should've checked for new answers before posting (took me an embarrassingly long time to write this out). Will mention in my post. Thank you

Comment: Thats the second reason I said hint, I didn't want to write it out myself, hahaha. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Let $\mathbb P(N = n)$ be the probability that $n$ defects are in the region $R$ and $X$ be the number of defects. Note that $\mathbb P(N = n | X = x) \sim \text{Binomial}(x,p)$, then:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(N = n,X = x) & =\mathbb P(N = n | X = x) \mathbb P(X = x) \\
& = \binom{x}{n} p^n (1-p)^{x - n} \frac{e^{-\alpha} \alpha^x}{x!}.
\end{align*}